# Double where clause in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to insert records into a table that are not listed in another table and also have a certain value in a field.  What I have came up with works but for some reason it only gives back those that have an APPROVED or APPROVED WITH CHANGES value in the APPROVAL STATE field and I am very confused on how to fix it.  Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

```
verifiedForm = "INSERT INTO VerifiedFormularies ([CLIENT ID], [CLIENT NAME], [MARKET SEGMENT], [FORMULARY ID], [FORMULARY NAME], [FORMULARY VERSION], [APPROVAL STATE]) " & _
               "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[CLIENT ID], DD.[CLIENT NAME], DD.[MARKET SEGMENT], DD.[FORMULARY ID], DD.[FORMULARY NAME], DD.[FORMULARY VERSION], DD.[APPROVAL STATE] " & _
               "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
               "Where DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT Exclusions.[Client ID] FROM Exclusions) " & _
                 "AND DD.[APPROVAL STATE] IN (""APPROVED AND PUBLISHED"",""APPROVED"",""APPROVED WITH POSTED CHANGES"",""APPROVED WITH CHANGES"") "
```

Comment: what do you mean it only gives back.. the insert fails? the select fails? as it doesn't include the approved and published values or what?

Comment: It only inserts the records that have APPROVED or APPROVED WITH CHANGES in the APPROVAL STATE field into the VerifiedFormularies table.

Comment: That's because either you have no records with an approval state in `tableName` with an `approval state` of approved and published or approved with posted changes'.  OR those that do exist, share the client ID in the exclusions table.  I'd have to see sample data to confirm this but the SQL looks right to me, so the error is likely data, or your expectation of results.  Show a record you expect to see in the results in your question and prove that it doesn't exist in the exclusions and has an approval state matching those listed. lastly normally I use ' instead of " when within blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this... replacing the in " with '.  I think you're doing this though VBA and I'm not sure how the driver treats " vs ' even if this is using ADO...  perhaps the driver doens't treat the "" correctly... but then I would expect "Approved with Changes" to fail as well...

but I'm leaning towards data issue or your expected results are incorrect.

```
verifiedForm = "INSERT INTO VerifiedFormularies ([CLIENT ID], [CLIENT NAME], [MARKET SEGMENT], [FORMULARY ID], [FORMULARY NAME], [FORMULARY VERSION], [APPROVAL STATE]) " & _
               "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[CLIENT ID], DD.[CLIENT NAME], DD.[MARKET SEGMENT], DD.[FORMULARY ID], DD.[FORMULARY NAME], DD.[FORMULARY VERSION], DD.[APPROVAL STATE] " & _
               "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
               "Where DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT Exclusions.[Client ID] FROM Exclusions) " & _
                 "AND DD.[APPROVAL STATE] IN ('APPROVED AND PUBLISHED','APPROVED','APPROVED WITH POSTED CHANGES','APPROVED WITH CHANGES') "
```

I'm not sure how access handles " vs ' though ....

What does `Select count(*), [approval state] from tablename group by [approval state]` return?
if 0 count on two missing, then data issue.

then what does...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename DD
LEFT JOIN exclusions E 
 on DD.[Client ID] = E.[Client ID]
WHERE DD.[Approval State] in (""APPROVED AND PUBLISHED"",""APPROVED WITH POSTED CHANGES"")
```

if no records then there are no client DD records with approval states not in the exclusions list.